# CustomValidator is not working into iOS 8

Tags: asp.net, validation, ios8, client-side-validation

The following code for client side customevalidator is working on IE, Safari, Chrome, iOS7 but it is not fire on iOS 8. Anyone have idea ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>   
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">       
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"
    ValidateEmptyText="true" ClientValidationFunction="alert('Firing')" ControlToValidate="txtName"
     Display="Dynamic"   >
</asp:CustomValidator>


<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save"   CausesValidation="true" 
     />

</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: i have the same problem on ios 9 mobile browser . safari Windows , will work just fine , and when i change the Safari Pc's Agent to mobile  , again it will work fine. but on mobile it will not work , any Idea ?????!?!?!